# How to prevent FastDateFormat pattern "yyyy-MM-dd" from parsing String in format "dd-MM-yyyy"

Tags: java, date

I have two format strings for date parsing: "yyyy-MM-dd" & "dd-MM-yyyy" and I was hoping that the FastDateFormat class would be able to distinguish between the two so that one would through a ParseException and the other would work. However both formats parse the same string values where one is obviously parsed correctly and the other is not.

My test code shows:

```
Parsed: "2014-06-06" into Fri Jun 06 00:00:00 EDT 2014 using "yyyy-MM-dd"
Parsed: "2014-06-06" into Sat Dec 05 00:00:00 EST 11 using "dd-MM-yyyy"
Parsed: "06-06-2014" into Sat Dec 05 00:00:00 EST 11 using "yyyy-MM-dd"
Parsed: "06-06-2014" into Fri Jun 06 00:00:00 EDT 2014 using "dd-MM-yyyy"
```

Is there any easy way to make FastDateFormat handle the 4 digit year properly based upon the pattern?"
I don't see any lenient settings on FastDateFormat.

Comment: I think you need to tag this question to something else also. Can't find it in `Java`.

Answer (score 4):

I can reproduce your results with [Apache-Common-Lang-library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.3.2/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/FastDateFormat.html). It seems the API does not offer any official solution, also not in newest version v3.3.2. Normally a good parser would reject the input 2014-06-06 for the pattern dd-MM-yyyy by throwing an exception but here `FastDateFormat` tolerates it and cannot even be set to non-lenient mode like `SimpleDateFormat`.

So the only options left are:

a) **Do your own hack** (similar to following code example):

```
public class ParserDDMMYYYY extends FastDateFormat {
  public static final INSTANCE = 
    new ParserDDMMYYYY("dd-MM-yyyy", TimeZone.getDefault(), Locale.getDefault());

  @Override
  public Date parse(String input) throws ParseException {
    if (input.charAt(4) == '-') {
      throw new ParseException("Invalid format: " + input, 0);
    }
    return super.parse(input);
  }

  // ... more overrides of similar parse methods
}
```

The case of preventing dd-MM-yyyy for the pattern yyyy-MM-dd is very similar.

b) **Or you change the date-time-library** since there are at least three better libraries around for date-time-handling and formatting. Keep in mind that the apache-library is still based on old `java.util.*`- and `java.text.*`-packages.

I also doubt if the class `FastDateFormat` is really so much better in performance, surely not better compared with the immutable versions of other date-time-libraries. For example I have seen some synchronized-keywords in the apache library (potential lock competition, not so modern).

Comment: What other "better libraries" would you suggest and I will check them out. Thanks.

Comment: @AwkOmo The two most popular and wide-spread libraries are JSR-310 (aka built-in java.time-package in Java-8) and Joda-Time. My own library Time4J is unknown, but also offers immutable types and formatters. All three libraries offer far more configuration options for formatting and parsing than `FastDateFormat`, for example strict parsing. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to format the parsed `Date` and compare the `String` with the original. This is more generic than checking if a specific character is in a specific location, but it's also slower. It allows you to let a user configure the format.

```
private final FastDateFormat myDateFormat = FastDateFormat.getInstance("dd-MM-yyyy");

public Date parseDate(String dateString) throws ParseException {
   final Date parsedDate = myDateFormat.parse(dateString);
   if(dateString != timeRangeDateFormat.format(parsedDate)){
      throw new ParseException("Strict mode engaged", 0);
   }
}
```